# Shannon Entropy over sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, quantum-information

For a project I am working with the JS-Divergence, where the divergence between random variables $P$ and $Q$ is given by
$$JSD = H(M) - \frac{1}{2} (H(P) + H(Q)),$$
with $M = \frac{P + Q}{2}$, and $H$ denotes the Shannon entropy over random variable $X$ with possible outcomes $x_1, ..., x_n$, i.e.
$$H(P) = - \sum_{i=1}^n P(x_i) \log P(x_i).$$
Considering the first term of JSD, we have that
$$H(M) = H(\frac{1}{2}P + \frac{1}{2}Q),$$
but how would I express this in terms of Shannon entropy? Is it the case that
$$H(\frac{1}{2}P + \frac{1}{2}Q) = -\sum \frac{1}{2}(P(x_i)+Q(x_i)) \log \frac{1}{2}(P(x_i)+Q(x_i)),$$
and if not, how else can I simplify $H(M)$? I would ideally rewrite the total expression in terms of the form $A \log B$, for random variables $A, B$. Any advise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's exactly what you have written. Please ignore the answer below which is incorrect. (More generically, entropy is a function of a distribution, which, for discrete laws, is just a vector in the appropriate simplex. Here you're working with the vector $M$ which is the arithmetic average of the vectors $P$ and $Q$). In general there is no simplification for $H(M)$ beyond what you have written.

Comment: You should clarify that $P$ and $Q$ are not really random variables but rather the distributions (hence the average is a mixture).

Answer (score 0):

Note that merely rescaling the *values* of a discrete random variable does not change its entropy, which merely depends on the *probabilities*.  Accordingly:

$H(\frac{1}{2}P+\frac{1}{2}Q) = H(P+Q)$

It is not immediately clear what we can do about the right-hand side of the above equation.  However, we might note that $P+Q$ clearly cannot contain more information than $PQ$ (as the former is a deterministic function of the latter), and we know that:

$H(PQ) = H(P) + H(Q) - I(P;Q)$

Accordingly, we have:

$H(P+Q) \leq H(P)+H(Q)$

Further analysis will require tackling both the $I(P;Q)$ term and any redundancies in the mapping from $PQ$ to $P+Q$.

Comment: This is wrong - they are working with the mixture law $(P+Q)/2,$ not a random variable $X+Y$.